# Difference between sum of hours and minutes using php

Tags: php, date, datetime

I want to calculate total number of hours and minutes difference with another total number of hours and minutes, For example:

```
$firsttotal = 181:33; ( 181 hours and 33 minutes)
$secondtotal = 315:00; (315 hours and 0 minutes)
```

so i want a way for calculating its difference like

```
$difference = 134:07 (134 hours and 7 minutes is the correct answer)
```

As php strtotime is not converting it and also php date function is not working on this.

Comment: Those are not valid numbers. Are they strings?

Comment: This value came from the sum of the total hours and minutes from database in the form of H:i. the query is SELECT  TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(attTime))), '%H.%i') as attTime FROM `attendance` and check database columns form time here in screenshot https://prnt.sc/ryye0f

Comment: So convert both values to their equivalent in minutes, add them - and then calculate and display the result in hour:minutes format again.

Comment: You should almost certainly do this computation in your database query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is (based on the two inputs) `133:27`, not `134:07`.

In PHP, you can do the following with minimal data checking.

```
// 181 hours and 33 minutes
$firsttotal = "181:33";
// 315 hours and 0 minutes
$secondtotal = "315:00";

// Convert to min.
// Assumes $str is a time in hhh:mm format only.
// For example, "181:33" is 181 hours and 33 min.
function toMin($str) {
    $tmp = explode(":",$str);
    return $tmp[1] + (60 * $tmp[0]);
}

// Return the difference in two min counts in HHH:MM format.
function diffToHHMM($min1,$min2) {
    $diff = $min2 - $min1;
    $h = floor($diff / 60);
    $m = ($diff % 60);
    return $h.":".$m;
}

$val1 = toMin($firsttotal); 
$val2 = toMin($secondtotal);

echo diffToHHMM($val1, $val2);
// Result: 133:27
```